Yolo predict wrong. Detect too many boxes
I just download the pre-trained model and try to predict. But this model detect too many boxes and wrong objects.
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from PIL import Image

model = YOLO("yolov5nu.pt")
model.info()
im1 = Image.open("images/giraffe.jpg")
results = model.predict(source=im1, save=True, save_txt=True)
cv2.imshow("YOLOv5 Detection", results[0].plot())
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

This is my code, it is very simple.
This is original image
This is result image
Log：
77 persons, 6 motorcycles, 4 buss, 1 truck, 14 traffic lights, 64 fire hydrants, 3 stop signs, 11 parking meters, 7 handbags, 3 snowboards, 20 sports balls, 7 baseball bats, 62 bottles, 3 spoons, 1 hot dog, 1 mouse, 1 remote, 2 vases, 2 hair driers, 11 toothbrushs, 481.0ms
Speed: 5.0ms preprocess, 481.0ms inference, 3.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
What happened？ The result is really weired. Do I need to re-train this model?

You don't need to retrain the model. It seems like there was an issue with the Ultralytics version. Try to update the Ultralytics library to the latest version or check this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78821012/16071964

@hanna_liavoshka thanks, I downgrading ultralytics version to  8.2.60. It works now!

This question is similar to: Alot of incorrect detection using YOLOv8. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

to address the issue of too many boxes and wrong objects being detected in your YOLO model, you can modify the confidence threshold parameter. This parameter helps filter out predictions with low confidence scores, reducing the number of false positives.
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from PIL import Image

model = YOLO("yolov5nu.pt")
model.info()

im1 = Image.open("images/giraffe.jpg")

results = model.predict(source=im1, conf=0.8, save=True, save_txt=True)

cv2.imshow("YOLOv5 Detection", results[0].plot())
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Adding conf=0.8 sets the confidence threshold to 0.8, meaning only predictions with a confidence score of 80% or higher will be considered. By default its value is 0.25, that's very low...

I fixed this by downgrading my Ultralytics version to 8.2.60.
